# Change flat XML structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My client always send me a flat XML file as shown below:

```
<Root>
  <ROW>
    <KIND>A</KIND>
    <DATA>Produc 1</DATA>
    <DATA>Details</DATA>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <KIND>A</KIND>
    <DATA>Product 2</DATA>
    <DATA>Details</DATA>
  </ROW>
    <ROW>
    <KIND>B</KIND>
    <DATA>Product 3</DATA>
    <DATA>Details</DATA>
    </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <KIND>B</KIND>
    <DATA>Product 4</DATA>
    <DATA>Details</DATA>
    </ROW>
</Root>
```

I need an XML grouped by KIND as following:

```
  <Root>
  <KIND>A
    <DATA>Product 1</DATA>
    <DATA>Details</DATA>
    <DATA>Product 2</DATA>
    <DATA>Details</DATA>
  </KIND>
  <KIND>B  
    <DATA>Product 3</DATA>
    <DATA>Details</DATA>
    <DATA>Product 4</DATA>
    <DATA>Details</DATA>
  </KIND>
</Root>
```

I don't now wow can I get it done? Thank you all.

Comment: XSLT 2.0. Will be used in Adobe InDesign.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 solves these types of grouping problems using the `for-each-group` instruction - there are many SO questions that explain how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5D+%22for-each-group%22). Let us know if you have specific issues as your attempt to solve.

Comment: Note: It is very poor processing form to have mixed content like you represent in your desired output. Mixing text (as in the "A") at the same level as elements (like the "Data" element). You should create some structure surrounding "A" or perhaps put the "A" in some attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ROW" group-by="KIND">
  <KIND>
    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/*"/>
  </KIND>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

But I agree with Kevin Brown - the design of your output is even worse than the design of the input.

Comment: Yes, i agree too. The input file is coming from excel and the output is intended to be used in a graphic design app, that's why it is so simple. Thank you all for helping me. :)